# Can you have a local Microsoft SQL Server be loaded into a cloud using PowerApps? If so how can you do this?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a project where I might have to stream my local SQL Server onto PowerApps. I was wondering if this is possible?

Comment: Disclaimer - I'm not well versed with PowerApps.  Stream?  I seriously doubt it unless you can use replication.  More description of what exactly you need to do would help here.  Do you mean use your local SQL Server instance as a data source for something in PowerApps?

Answer (score 0):

You can [Connect to SQL Server from PowerApps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-azure-sqldatabase)

> Connect to SQL Server, in either Azure or an on-premises database, so
> that you can manage your data with create, read, update, and delete
> operations.

For an on-prem SQL Server you'll need a [Data Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/gateway-management).